# Cleaner way of returning HashMap's Collection view?

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, hashmap

I'm trying to understand the way of doing things in cleaner way. Correct me if I'm doing anything wrong, I have a function,

```
 Collection<Object> x(Collection<Object> input){
     Map<Double,Object> map = new HashMap<Double,Object>();
     //do some processing

     return map.values();
 }
```

Now does this make Entry objects to live in the memory, as values() wrap entrySet(), in this scenario is it better to collect all values() Collection into another Collection and return and another thing is, are we leaking memory (unneeded objects)if we return HashMap's Collection view?

Comment: It really depends on how you're using the method, as well as your memory and performance constraints.

Comment: From [`Map#values()`'s documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#values--): "*Returns a Collection view of the values contained in this map. The collection is backed by the map [...]*". As long as you have a reference to the returned value fo `values()`, the `Map` will not be gc'ed.

Answer (score 2):

> does this make Entry objects to live in the memory

yes, since the returned collection simply delegates to the HashMap

> is it better to collect all values() Collection into another Collection

In general, no. It might be useful in rare cases, where you want a more compact, or a serializable collection, or a more specific collection type (a Set, or a List)

> are we leaking memory

No. The collection, and thus the HashMap it delegates to, will eventually be garbage collected, as any other Java object.

Comment: Does it mean HashMap is not garbage collected until we hold the values() Collection reference?, I'm confused because here we are referencing Map.Entry, not the HashMap reference itself?

Comment: Yes, it means that. I don't know where you got that the collection doesn't reference the map. It does, as the documentation says, and as the code shows.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. In places both entrySet() and values() , HashMap is referenced. Thanks for the answer.